# I have some problems with ArrayList (quiz of head first java)

Tags: java, string, oop, arraylist, integer

I've just started learning java since last week. I'm using book called 'head first java' and i'm struggling with solving problems about ArrayList. Error says "The method setLocationCells(ArrayList) in the type DotCom is not applicable for the
arguments (int[])" and I haven't found the solution :( help me..!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7D0H.png)

Comment: Hello. Please don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)) but as formatted text. Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: "The method setLocationCells(ArrayList) in the type DotCom is not applicable for the arguments (int[])" ArrayList is not related to int[] array and Java will not convert `int[]` automatically to `ArrayList`. If you want to pass `int[]` as argument create method which will accept `int[]` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Locate & Conquer type game *similar* to the game named **Battleship** with the exception that this game is a single player game played with a single hidden ship in a single horizontal row of columnar characters. Rather simplistic but kind of fun to play I suppose. The hard part is to **locate** the hidden ship but once you've located it, **conquering** (sinking) it becomes relatively easy. I'm sure this isn't the games' intent since it is after all named "The Dot Com Game" but the analogy could be possibly helpful.

There are several issues with your code but there are two major ones that just can not be there for the game to work:

---

**Issue #1: The call to the `DotCom.setLocationCells()` method:**

The initial problem is located within the **DotComGame** class on code **line 13** (as the Exception indicates) where the call is made to the `DotCom.setLocationCells()` method. As already mentioned in comments the wrong parameter type is passed to this method. You can not pass an `int[]` Array to the `setLocationCell()` method when this method contains a parameter signature that stipulates it requires an `ArrayList` object. The best solution in my opinion would be to satisfy the `setLocationCells()` method parameter requirement...supply an `ArrayList` to this method.

The reason I say this is because all methods within the **DotCom** class work with an established ArrayList and one of the tasks of one of these methods (the `checkYourself()` method) actually removes elements from the ArrayList which is easy to do from a collection but very cumbersome to do the same from an Array.

To fix this problem you will need to change the data type for the `locations` variable located within the **DotComGame** class. Instead of using:

```
int[] locations = {randomNum, randomNum + 1, randomNum + 2};
```

you should have:

```
ArrayList<Integer> locations = new ArrayList<>(
     Arrays.asList(random, randomNum + 1, randomNum + 2));
```

or you could do it this way:

```
ArrayList<Integer> locations = new ArrayList<>();
    locations.add(randomNum);
    locations.add(randomNum + 1);
    locations.add(randomNum + 2);
```

There are other ways but these will do for now. Now, when the call to the `setLocationCells()` method is made you ahouldn't get an exception this issue should now be resolved.

---

**Issue #2: The call to the `DotCom.checkYourself()` method:**

Again, this particular issue is located within the **DotComGame** class on code **line 18** where the call is made to the `DotCom.checkYourself()` method. Yet another parameter data type mismatch. You are trying to pass a variable of type `String` (named `guess`) to this method whereas its signature stipulates that it requires an integer (`int`) value. That again is a no go.

To fix this problem you will need to convert the string numerical value held by the `guess` variable to an Integer (`int`) value. So instead of having this:

```
while(isAlive) {
    String guess = helper.getUserInput("Enter a Number: ");
    String result = theDotCom.checkYourself(guess);
    // ... The rest of your while loop code ...
}
```

you should have something like:

```
while(isAlive) {
    String guess = helper.getUserInput("Enter a Number: ");
    /* Validate. Ensure guess holds a string representation
       of a Integer numerical value.           */
    if (!guess.matches("\\d+")) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Value (" + guess 
                         + ") Supplied! Try again...");
        continue;
    }
    int guessNum = Integer.parseInt(guess);
    String result = theDotCom.checkYourself(guessNum);
    numOfGuesses++;
    if (result.equals("kill")) {
        isAlive = false;
        System.out.println(numOfGuesses + " guesses!");
    }
    else if (result.equals("hit")) {
        // Do Something If You Like
        System.out.println("HIT!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Missed!");
    }
}
```

Below is a game named Simple Battleship which I based off of your code images (please don't use images for code anymore - I hate using online OCR's ;)

**BattleshipGame.java** - The application start class:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class BattleshipGame {

        public static int gameLineLength = 10;
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameHelper helper = new GameHelper();
        Battleship theDotCom = new Battleship();
        int score = 0;  // For keeping an overall score
        
        // Display About the game...
        System.out.println("Simple Battleship Game");
        System.out.println("======================");
        System.out.println("In  this  game  you will be  displayed a  line of  dashes.");
        System.out.println("Each  dash  has the  potential  to  hide a  section  of  a");
        System.out.println("hidden  Battleship.  The  size of this  ship  is  randomly");
        System.out.println("chosen by the  game engine and can be from 1 to 5 sections");
        System.out.println("(characters) in length. The score for each battle is based");
        System.out.println("on the length  of  the game line that will be displayed to");
        System.out.println("you  (default is a minimum of 10 charaters).  You now have");
        System.out.println("the option to supply the game line length you want to play");
        System.out.println("with.  If you want to use the default then just hit ENTER:");
        System.out.println();
        
        // Get the desire game line length
        String length = helper.getUserInput("Desired Game Line Length: --> ", "Integer", true, 10, 10000);
        if (!length.isEmpty()) {
            gameLineLength = Integer.parseInt(length);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // Loop to allow for continuous play...
        boolean alwaysReplay = true;
        while (alwaysReplay) {
            int numOfGuesses = 0;
            
            /* Create a random ship size to hide within the line.
               It could be a size from 1 to 5 characters in length.   */
            int shipSize = new java.util.Random().nextInt((5 - 1) + 1) + 1;
            int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * (gameLineLength - (shipSize - 1)));
            int[] locations = new int[shipSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                locations[i] = randomNum + i;
            }
            
            System.out.println("Destroy the " + shipSize + " character ship hidden in the");
            System.out.println("displayed line below:");
            System.out.println();
            String gameLine = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(gameLineLength, "-"));
            theDotCom.setLocationCells(locations);
            
            // Play current round...
            boolean isAlive = true;
            while (isAlive == true) {
                System.out.println(gameLine);
                String guess = helper.getUserInput("Enter a number from 1 to " + gameLineLength
                        + " (0 to quit): --> ", "Integer", 1, gameLineLength);
                int idx = Integer.parseInt(guess);
                if (idx == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Quiting with an overall score of: " + score + " ... Bye-Bye");
                    alwaysReplay = false;
                    break;
                }
                idx = idx - 1;
                String result = theDotCom.checkYourself(idx);
                numOfGuesses++;
                System.out.println(result);
                if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("kill")) {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    isAlive = false;
                    /* Tally the score dependent upon the gameLineLength...  */
                    if (gameLineLength <= 10) { score += 5; }
                    else if (gameLineLength > 10 && gameLineLength <= 20) { score += 10; }
                    else if (gameLineLength > 20 && gameLineLength <= 30) { score += 15; }
                    else if (gameLineLength > 30 && gameLineLength <= 40) { score += 20; }
                    else { score += 25; }
                    gameLine = gameLine.substring(0, idx) + "x" + gameLine.substring(idx + 1);
                    System.out.println(gameLine);
                    System.out.println(numOfGuesses + " guesses were made to sink the hidden ship.");
                    System.out.println("Your overall score is: " + (score < 0 ? 0 : score));
                }
                else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("hit")) {
                    gameLine = gameLine.substring(0, idx) + "x" + gameLine.substring(idx + 1);
                }
                if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("miss")) {
                    score -= 1;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            // Play Again? [but only if 'alwaysReplay' holds true]
            if (alwaysReplay) {
                String res = helper.getAnything("<< Press ENTER to play again >>\n"
                                          + "<<   or enter 'q' to quit    >>");
                if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                    System.out.println("Quiting with an overall score of: " + score + " ... Bye-Bye");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GameHelper.java** - The GameHelper class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameHelper {
   
    private final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public String getUserInput(String prompt, String responseType, int... minMAX) {
        int min = 0, max = 0;
        if (minMAX.length == 2) {
            min = minMAX[0];
            max = minMAX[1];
        }
        if (minMAX.length > 0 && min < 1 || max < 1) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("\n\ngetUserInput() Method Error! "
                     + "The optional parameters 'min' and or 'max' can not be 0!\n\n");
        }
        
        String response = "";
        while (response.isEmpty()) {
            if (prompt.trim().endsWith("-->")) {
                System.out.print(prompt);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(prompt);
            }
            response = in.nextLine().trim();
            if (responseType.matches("(?i)\\b(int|integer|float|double)\\b")) {
                if (!response.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") || 
                        (responseType.toLowerCase().startsWith("int") && response.contains("."))) {
                    System.err.println("Invalid Entry (" + response + ")! Try again...");
                    response = "";
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // Check entry range value if the entry is to be an Integer
            if (responseType.toLowerCase().startsWith("int")) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(response);
                if (i != 0 && (i < min || i > max)) {
                    System.err.println("Invalid Entry (" + response + ")! Try again...");
                    response = "";
                }
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
    
    public String getUserInput(String prompt, String responseType, boolean allowNothing, int... minMAX) {
        int min = 0, max = 0;
        if (minMAX.length == 2) {
            min = minMAX[0];
            max = minMAX[1];
        }
        if (minMAX.length > 0 && min < 1 || max < 1) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("\n\ngetUserInput() Method Error! "
                     + "The optional parameters 'min' and or 'max' can not be 0!\n\n");
        }
        
        String response = "";
        while (response.isEmpty()) {
            if (prompt.trim().endsWith("-->")) {
                System.out.print(prompt);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(prompt);
            }
            response = in.nextLine().trim();
            if (response.isEmpty() && allowNothing) {
                return "";
            }
            if (responseType.matches("(?i)\\b(int|integer|float|double)\\b")) {
                if (!response.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") || 
                        (responseType.toLowerCase().startsWith("int") && response.contains("."))) {
                    System.err.println("Invalid Entry (" + response + ")! Try again...");
                    response = "";
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // Check entry range value if the entry is to be an Integer
            if (responseType.toLowerCase().startsWith("int")) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(response);
                if (i != 0 && (i < min || i > max)) {
                    System.err.println("Invalid Entry (" + response + ")! Try again...");
                    response = "";
                }
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
    
    public String getAnything(String prompt) {
        if (prompt.trim().endsWith("-->")) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(prompt);
        }
        return in.nextLine().trim();
    }
}
```

**Battleship.java** - The Battleship class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Battleship {
    
    private ArrayList<Integer> locationCells;
    
    public void setLocationCells(java.util.ArrayList<Integer> loc) {
        locationCells = loc;
    }
    
    // Overload Method (Java8+)
    public void setLocationCells(int[] loc) {
        locationCells = java.util.stream.IntStream.of(loc)
                                   .boxed()
                                   .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors
                                           .toCollection(java.util.ArrayList::new));
    }
    
    /* 
    // Overload Method (Before Java8)
    public void setLocationCells(int[] loc) {
        // Clear the ArrayList in case it was previously loaded.
        locationCells.clear(); 
        // Fill the ArrayList with integer elements from the loc int[] Array
        for (int i = 0; i < loc.length; i++) {
            locationCells.add(loc[i]);
        }
    }
    */
    
    /**
     * Completely removes one supplied Integer value from all elements
     * within the supplied Integer Array if it exist.<br><br>
     * 
     * <b>Example Usage:</b><pre>
     *
     * {@code     int[] a = {103, 104, 100, 10023, 10, 140, 2065};
     *      a = removeFromArray(a, 104);
     *      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a);
     *
     *      // Output will be:  [103, 100, 10023, 10, 140, 2065]}</pre>
     *
     * @param srcArray     (Integer Array) The Integer Array to remove elemental
     *                     Integers from.<br>
     *
     * @param intToDelete (int) The Integer to remove from elements within the 
     *                    supplied Integer Array.<br>
     *
     * @return A Integer Array with the desired elemental Integers removed.
     */
    public static int[] removeFromArray(int[] srcArray, int intToDelete) {
        int[] arr = {};
        int cnt = 0;
        boolean deleteIt = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < srcArray.length; i++) {
            if (srcArray[i] != intToDelete) {
                arr[cnt] = srcArray[i];
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
    
    public String checkYourself(int userInput) {
        String result = "MISS"; 
        int index = locationCells.indexOf(userInput); 
        if (index >= 0) { 
            locationCells.remove(index); 
            if (locationCells.isEmpty()) { 
                result = "KILL"; 
            } 
            else { 
                result = "HIT";
            }
        } 
        return result; 
    }
}
```